# Multiple targets in next-http-proxy-middleware

Tags: next.js, http-proxy

What to do if I want to have multiple targets in my next-http-proxy-middleware.
It would be great to have the possibility to chain proxy middlewares like this, but id does not work:

```
httpProxyMiddleware(req, res, {
  target: process.env.target1,
  pathRewrite: [{
    patternStr: "^/api", replaceStr: "",
  }],
}).then((response)=>httpProxyMiddleware(req, response, {
  target: process.env.target2,
  pathRewrite: [{
    patternStr: "^/s3", replaceStr: "",
  }],
}))
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: There is a typo, not sure if this will make it work though: `than` => `then`

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested in https://github.com/stegano/next-http-proxy-middleware/issues/52#issuecomment-999980770?